# get id of button by clicked with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

html

```
<button id="test1" onclick="getclickname(); return false;">click</button>
```

javascript (it's showing "Undefined")

```
   function getclickname()
   {
   alert(this.id);
   }
```

i dont want code like this

```
<button id="test1" onclick="alert(this.id);">click</button>
```

call getclickname is needed, thanks guys

Comment: Better to [avoid inline handlers entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045)

Comment: if you didn't pass argument then how to get in alert... `alert(this.id);`

Comment: Inside button ``onclick="getclickname(this.id)"``    and function getclickname(buttonId) { alert(buttonId);}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass corresponding argument to the function.

1. You need to pass button object to `onclick` function to get the `id` of button.

```js
function getclickname(obj)
    {
      //By passing object as argument you can access all properties of that element
      alert(obj.id);
      alert(obj.className);
    }
```

```html
<button id="test1" onclick="getclickname(this); return false;" class="test_1">click</button>
```

2. You can directly pass `this.id` as well as an argument

```js
function getclickname(id) {
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<button id="test1" onclick="getclickname(this.id); return false;">click</button>
```

***Note:***

- A bit code modification is instead of `return false;` you can add `return` before function name and that will do the same thing. like :- `onclick="return getclickname(this.id);"`
- By passing object as argument you can access all properties of that element (check first code sample modification).

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code. It's working for you.

Use class for click event in button.

```
<button id="test1" class="test-btn" >click</button>
```

Use the below click event function to get id after click.

```
$('.test-btn').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Helpful...

**view**

```
onclick="return getclickname(this);"
```

**js**

```
function getclickname(these)
{
   alert(these.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
<button id="test1" onclick="getclickname(this); return false;">click</button>
<script>
   function getclickname(e)
   {
   alert(e.id);
   }
</script>
```